# Java JPanel wont scroll

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make image scrollable using jPanel and jFrame in java. I'm draw my image in drawQuestion class then I add drawQuestion to jScrollPanel and It doesn't scroll. Please Tell me where my error is I've been trying to find for days and I still cant find it.
Sorry for my bad English.

main.java:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class main{

private static int width = 800;
private static int height = 450;

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame window = new JFrame("DPA Physics 2013 9 class");
    drawQuestion question = new drawQuestion();
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(question);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(width,height);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    window.add(scroll);

    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

drawQuestion.java:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class drawQuestion extends JPanel{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Image image1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Page1.png")).getImage();

    g.drawImage(image1,0,0,this);
}
}
```

Comment: 1) `drawQuestion` should be called `DrawQuestion` or better `DrawableQuestion` and it should *return a preferred size the same size as the image.* 2) `Image image1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Page1.png")).getImage();`  The image should be either loaded when the panel is created, or passed to the panel in the constructor. 3) Far easier is to display the image in a `JLabel` in a scroll pane.  [E.G.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13463684/418556)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've not specified a (preferred) size for the `drawQuestion` panel, which means all the layouts now think it's 0x0 in size....

You should NEVER load or perform any task that may take even a small amount of time to complete within any `paint` method...

You need to override the `getPreferredSize` method to return the required size of the panel.  This will allow the scroll pane to determine if the panel needs scrolling...

```
public class DrawQuestion extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Image image1;
    public DrawQuestion() {
        image1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("Page1.png")).getImage();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return image1 == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(image1.getWidth(this), image1.getHeight(this));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (image1 != null) {
            g.drawImage(image1,0,0,this);
        }
    }
}
```

While I'm on my wall...I'd also recommend `ImageIO` over `ImageIcon` as `ImageIO` will throw exceptions if the image can't be loaded...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Technically, min or max as well, but yes - updated