# Java JPanel & JScrollPane

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I working on a application that manage image's filters etc.

I want to have scroll bars when the image is to big to be display.
I put my customize panel that extend `JPanel` in a `JScrollPane` and I add it in my `JFrame`.

My image is displayed but not the whole image and the scroll bars are not there.

How to get the scroll-bars to appear?

Here is my code :

```
CustomePanel test = new ImagePanel(new File("test.jpg"));
test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
JScrollPane tmp = new JScrollPane(test);
this.getContentPane().add(tmp);
```

Comment: [`ImageViewer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13463684/418556) is a working example.  If you cannot sort it out based on that code, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Comment: *"and I add it in my Frame"*  DYM a `java.awt.Frame` or a `javax.swing.JFrame`?  Don't mix Swing & AWT components without good reason.  BTW - I added *"How to get the scroll-bars to appear?"* to the question, since it lacked one (a question, that is).  If that is ***not*** your question, ask one of your own.

Comment: my bad, indeed it is JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your initial preferred size does not match that of your `Image`. Rather than using `setPreferredSize`,  override `getPreferredSize` to reflect the size of the image in `ImagePanel`:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
   return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this)); 
}
```

A `JLabel` would be a better approach here if the panel is not required as a container.

Comment: That works, thank you a lot. May I ask you something ? I get my scrollbar on the left, and i would like to have a second on the bottom, how can i make it ?

Comment: I don't really see the advantage of using a panel where a label fits better.

Comment: Thanks again.I'm using a panel because it's mandatory on what i'm working on ^^'

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would agree provided that the panel is not required for use as a container

Comment: @user2339951 Can't replicate the scrollbar issue so will ask you to post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson nop, a project in my job.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the same preferred size to scroll pane as well and test it