# Frame for a lot of information

Tags: java, swing

This might be an odd question, so I beg you guys to bear with me on this.

I want to present information to a `JFrame`. Particularly, a `String`.

Here's the catch, it's a very very long `String`. Like, miles. Think several dozen lines of information in total.

It's a little like a phone-book, with more names than you can possibly fit on a page, and you only have that one page to use.

So I'm thinking scrollbars.

I tried:

```
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(veryLongText.toString());
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);
```

But that didn't work, as I couldn't scroll down until I added more text. Which wasn't what I was going for.

To put it simply, I want a text box that I can scroll in if the window is too small to fit all the text inside it.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting it up to allow for line wrapping...

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(veryLongText.toString());
area.setLineWrap(true);
```

> Sets the line-wrapping policy of the text area. If set to true the
>   lines will be wrapped if they are too long to fit within the allocated
>   width. If set to false, the lines will always be unwrapped. A
>   PropertyChange event ("lineWrap") is fired when the policy is changed.
>   By default this property is false.

Can even wrap on word boundaries by using...

```
area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

> Sets the style of wrapping used if the text area is wrapping lines. If
>   set to true the lines will be wrapped at word boundaries (whitespace)
>   if they are too long to fit within the allocated width. If set to
>   false, the lines will be wrapped at character boundaries. By default
>   this property is false.

Generally, I suggest both

Take a look at the [`JTextArea` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) and [How to use text areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more details...

Comment: This was just what I was looking for (despite not knowing it was), thank you, friend!

Comment: Good catch on the text wrapping.

Comment: Welcome to the forest, watch out for the trees ;)

Answer (score 4):

> It's a little like a phone-book, with more names than you can possibly fit on a page

I'd recommend a `JList` or `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`.

See 'how to use X' in your favorite search engine, where 'x' is any of the above three, for more details.

Comment: I am disappointed you deleted your comment as it was a relevant link, especially for anyone who decides to use the oracle tutorials.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, the comment on my answer. I commented here before you commented on my answer again.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track with `JScrollPane`. I highly suggested you look at the [JScrollPane tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

In a nutshell, you will want to use the following piece of code:

```
//In a container that uses a BorderLayout:
textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
...
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
...
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This means that everything in your `textArea` will be scrollable. You can replace that with  a `JPanel` if it is more appropriate.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That was literally a copy-paste from the Oracle docs. But I will remove it because I agree.

Comment: The code snippet above corrects a problem in the official tutorial it refers to. +1  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you didn't have enough text to make it scroll. Your solution seems correct.

Maybe you want the scrollbar to be always there, use the other constructor: [`JScrollPane(Component, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int%29) with constants from [`ScrollPaneConstants`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ScrollPaneConstants.html).

Comment: *"Maybe you want the scrollbar to be always there.."* E.G. as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21849351/418556) which declares horizontal bar always, vertical bar never.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling your string is one very very long line.  Does it have any new line characters in it?  ie "\n"?

Anyhoo, here's an example that works

```
//
//  Test ScrollPane with very very long string
//
package testjscrollpane;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestJScrollPane extends JFrame
{
    public TestJScrollPane()
    {
        //Create a long long string
        String s = "";
        int n = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
            s += Integer.toString(i)+"  ";

            //this next part breaks the string up into lots of lines
            //if commentted out, the whole string will appear on 1 line
            //with no vertical scrollbar
//            n++;
//            if(n==100)
//            {
//                s += "\n";
//                n = 0;
//            }
        }

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation((JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE));
        this.setSize(400, 400);

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(s);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(area);
        this.add(scrollpane);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestJScrollPane myFrame = new TestJScrollPane();
    }

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Support for line wrapping and word wrapping is provide by `JTextArea` already...which takes into consideration things like font metrics automatically...

Comment: I'll take your word for it, but when I experimented no wordwrap happened.  I'm guessing it doesn't by default, and the 2 lines the OP gave us had no mention of turning them on.  I'm still betting his scroll pane shows 1 really long line because it doesn't have any new line characters in it.

Comment: Line wrapping shouldn't (from my pathetic memory) association with white space...