# Display moving image in Java Swing

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm trying to display a high-width image in Java Swing (say 2000x100, like a heart rate strip). I need to show only a window of 500 width while it is slightly moving towards left. My current code (a bit complicated, it also has unnecessary animations) does it, but the feature I need to add is: The end of image should be concatenated with the beginning of the image. So it always repeats showing over and over.

In short, I need to join the two ends of image! How can I do that?

[image]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SlidingAnimation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SlidingAnimation();
    }

    public SlidingAnimation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel j = new JPanel();
                j.add(new AnimatedBar(true));
                frame.add(j);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class AnimatedBar extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;

    private Timer timer;
    private long startTime = -1;
    private int playTime = 4000;
    private int window = 500;
    private int moveX=0;
    public static boolean keepRunning=true;

    private float progress;

    public AnimatedBar(boolean x) {
        try {
            if(x)
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("strip2.jpg"));
            else
                img=null;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(x){
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (startTime == -1) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else {
                        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long diff = currentTime - startTime;

                        if (diff >= playTime) {
                            diff = 0;
                            startTime = -1;
                        }
                        progress = diff / (float) playTime;
                    }

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return img == null ? new Dimension(50, 50) : new Dimension(img.getWidth()/3, img.getHeight());
    }

    protected BufferedImage generateImage() {

        BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
        g2d.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, buffer.getWidth(), buffer.getHeight());
        //            g2d.drawImage(img, 500, 0, this);
        g2d.drawImage(img,0,0,500,100,(moveX++),0,window+moveX,100,this);


        float startAt = progress- 0.05f;
        float endAt = progress + 0.05f;

        if (endAt <= 0.1f) {
            startAt = 0;
            endAt = Math.max(0.1f, progress);
        } else if (endAt >= 1f) {
            endAt = 1f;
            startAt = progress;
        }

        LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                new Point2D.Float(0, 0),
                new Point2D.Float(img.getWidth(), 0),
                new float[]{startAt, endAt},
                new Color[]{new Color(0, 0, 0, 0), Color.RED});

        g2d.setPaint(lgp);

        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstOut.derive(1f));
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        g2d.dispose();

        return buffer;

    }

    public void setImg(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(keepRunning==false){
            img=null;
        }
        else{
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("strip2.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()/3) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(generateImage(), x, y, this);

                g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513) using [tag:jfreechart].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The end of image should be concatenated with the beginning of the image. So it always repeats showing

Check out the [Marquee Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/). You can add a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon` to the `MarqueePanel`.

The `MarqueePanel` provides various method to customize the scrolling.

Edit:

The basic code would be:

```
MarqueePanel panel = new MarqueePanel();
panel.setWrap(true);
panel.setWrapAmount(0);
panel.setPreferredWidth(250);

JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon( "heartbeat.jpg" ) );
panel.add( label );

frame.add( panel );
```

If you want the image to fully appear at the left when it is displayed you can change the `startScrolling()` method and use `scrollOffset = 0;`.

Comment: Thanks. But as can be seen, when the text ends and goes away, it starts again. Like a circle, I need the text start ASA it ends, so the end is glued to the start!

Comment: Ummm, the 'wrap' option might help. I hope there could be no space in between of two ends supposed to join together.

Comment: @TinaJasmin, you will also have to set the `wrap amount` to 0 when using `wrap` if you don't want a gap.

Comment: Can you kindly point me to a sample code using the above heart strip image? This seems an interesting and easy approach. Just want to make sure the gap will really remain 0.

Comment: That's good. But the only thing I need to do is the start phase! Is it possible to first fill the display window, then move left? Basically I do not want to see any spaces/gaps!

Comment: `Is it possible to first fill the display window,` - already answered in the edit I made.

Comment: I changed my mind and chose your answer as the best answer! So far so good. But there is a minor problem! When the window is selected and focused, the image moves, but when I click on another window, it stops! How can I make it always move?

Comment: OK, got my answer! setScrollWhenFocused :)

Answer (score 7):

To join the ends, paint the image twice as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18825844/418556). The first paint would be the end of the image. The second paint would be the start of the image, offset by the width the end goes to.

E.G.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class HeartBeat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8UJD.jpg");
        final BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(url);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(
                        bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                final JLabel animationLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(canvas));
                ActionListener animator = new ActionListener() {

                    int x = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Graphics2D g = canvas.createGraphics();

                        // paint last part of image in left of canvas
                        g.drawImage(bi, x, 0, null);
                        // paint first part of image immediately to the right
                        g.drawImage(bi, x + bi.getWidth(), 0, null);

                        // reset x to prevent hitting integer overflow
                        if (x%bi.getWidth()==0) x = 0;

                        g.dispose();
                        animationLabel.repaint();
                        x--;
                    }
                };
                Timer timer = new Timer(40, animator);
                timer.start();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, animationLabel);
                timer.stop();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe add a comment or two where you get the offset explaining what exactly is going on there? I think that would be useful for people trying to work through how the image wraps.

Comment: As just a quick note, depending on what this display is being used for, you may want to reset x when it mods to 0... otherwise I think you'll run into a negative integer overflow in like three years... probably doesn't matter, but maybe.

Comment: This is a nice one! But can you add an option with a value (maybe a timer?) to specify moving step by step in a discrete way as opposed to continuously moving? like, when 'step=0' it could be like now, and when 'step=10', it moves every 10 pixels. Maybe you can add Also some comments to describe the logic can be awesome :)

Comment: *"Also some comments to describe the logic"*   Yes, I added them.  There really isn't that much logic to explain. *"But can you add an option.."* I'll leave that as an exercise for the end user.  In any case, it seems that *"I need to join the two ends of image! How can I do that?"* has already been answered (using two different approaches).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I'm facing with a stupid question! How can I add the moving image to an external jpanel? like jp1.add(HeartBeat)

Comment: *"How can I add the moving image to an external jpanel?"* That is worthy of another (new) question, but make sure you define 'external' clearly.  I'm not sure what you mean by it.