# Embed a moving image inside another jpanel

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to move, and display an image (e.g. heart rate image). Here is what I have so far. The image keeps moving to the left forvever; so far so good. But I need to embed this moving image inside another frame. I know my question seems very

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class HeartBeat extends JPanel{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new HeartBeat();    
    }

    public HeartBeat(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel j = new JPanel();
                j.add(new HeartBeat2());
                frame.add(j);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    class HeartBeat2 extends JPanel{
        BufferedImage bi;

        public HeartBeat2(){
        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8UJD.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(
                        bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                final JLabel animationLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(canvas));
                ActionListener animator = new ActionListener() {

                    int x = 0;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Graphics2D g = canvas.createGraphics();

                        // paint last part of image in left of canvas
                        g.drawImage(bi, x, 0, null);
                        // paint first part of image immediately to the right
                        g.drawImage(bi, x + bi.getWidth(), 0, null);

                        // reset x to prevent hitting integer overflow
                        if (x%bi.getWidth()==0) x = 0;

                        g.dispose();
                        animationLabel.repaint();
                        x--;
                    }
                };
                Timer timer = new Timer(40, animator);
                timer.start();
                JPanel j = new JPanel();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, animationLabel);
                timer.stop();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Okay, you have the `JPanel`, you can add it to what ever you like, not sure I see the problem...

Comment: `Here is my code.` You mean here is the code you copied from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519141/display-moving-image-in-java-swing/26519276#26519276. I also don't understand the question. You have a JLabel, so just add it to the frame.

Comment: I meant the code I have so far. Yes, basically I put inside my frame, and simply add the JLabel to the other jpanel. But for some reasons it does not show the moving image!

Comment: Of course! Any label should simply be added to any jpanel. But for some reasons I dont see anything...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is

1. The `animationLabel` is being added to the `JOptionPane`, but you never add it to the `HeartBeat2`
2. The `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` is a blocking (modal) call, so it blocks any code occurring after it (i.e. `timer.stop()`). But if you remove that `JOptionPane` (to try and add the label to the panel) the `timer.stop()` will automatically be called (The timer is controlling the image/animation). And if you just *leave* the `JOptionPane` there, the adding the label to panel won't work, as each component can only have one parent

So you need to

1. First of all, completely strip out the `Runnable`. You don't need it.
2. Take out the `JOptionPane`, and simply `add(animationLabel)` to the `HeartBeat2`
3. Take out the `timer.stop()`

---

```
public HeartBeat2() {

    try {
        bi = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8UJD.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    final BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(
            bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    final JLabel animationLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(canvas));
    add(animationLabel);

    ActionListener animator = new ActionListener() {

        int x = 0;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Graphics2D g = canvas.createGraphics();

            // paint last part of image in left of canvas
            g.drawImage(bi, x, 0, null);
            // paint first part of image immediately to the right
            g.drawImage(bi, x + bi.getWidth(), 0, null);

            // reset x to prevent hitting integer overflow
            if (x % bi.getWidth() == 0) {
                x = 0;
            }

            g.dispose();
            animationLabel.repaint();
            x--;
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer(40, animator);
    timer.start();
}
```