# Display random images from folder to JLabel in Netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, random, netbeans-7

My project contains a folder named images containing images.  I want to display the images randomly to the `JLabel` in the frame when a button pressed.  I tried the code below:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {
    Image im=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/a1.jpg")).getImage();
    ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon(im);
    jLabel2.setIcon(iconLogo);
 }
```

This code displays only the image a1.  But I need the images randomly (one image at a time).

Comment: Check [`ImageViewer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13463684/418556) for tips on displaying multiple images.  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556) (another way is shown in the `ImageViewer` code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use something like

```
..getResource("/images/a" + randomNumber + ".jpg")
```

Genderate a random number for `randomNumber` variable. As long as all your images have the same prefix and just different numerical suffix, you should be fine.

---

If they're all different, then store each string path into a String array and the random number will be the index

```
getResource("/images/" + pathArray[randomNumber])
```

**Example**

```
String[] imageNames {"hello.jpg", "world.png", "!.gif"};
Random rand = rand = new Random();
....
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    int index = rand.nextInt(3);

    Image im=new ImageIcon(this.getClass()
                .getResource("/images/" + imageNames[index])).getImage();
    ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon(im);
    jLabel2.setIcon(iconLogo);
}
```

---

**UPDATE** to OP comment

> *"Oh!if the folder contains 100 pictures it seems very difficult.My project needs more images"*

then load the filed names into a data structure via the `File API`.. `file.list()` <-- return a `String[]`

```
File file = new File("src/images");
String[] imageNames = file.list(); 
...
int index = rand.nextInt(imagNames.length);
```

As long as all the files are files and not directories, this should work fine.

---

**UPDATE**

As discussed below in the comments, its been noted that the above answer will probably not work at time of deployment. Here is @AndrewThompson's suggestion as a fix to the file problem

> The best way I can think of is:
>
> 1. Create a small helper class that creates a list of the images.
> 2. Write that list to a `File`, one name per line.
> 3. Include the file as a resource (the easiest place is where the images are).
> 4. Use `getResource(String)` to gain an `URL` to it.
> 5. Read it back in at run-time.

Comment: if the folder contains different images like png,jpg,jpeg?

Comment: You put all the file names into a String array

Comment: Oh!if the folder contains 100 pictures it seems very difficult.My project needs more images.

Comment: @user3164246, then load the filed names into a data structure via the `File API`.. `file.list()`

Comment: @AndrewThompson how would _you_ load the file names, for the sake of deployment? I'm not too sure