# How can I make image appear randomly every x seconds in java using timer?

Tags: java, random, timer, jpanel

I'm working on a game in which I need to 'hit' a mouse/rat, it will disappear and you'll get 1 point.
I made it randomly appear everytime i start the app, but I want the image te be drawn randomly every x seconds using Timer() or something.

My code for the game screen looks like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Gamevenster extends JPanel implements Runnable {
        public String Gamestatus = "active";
        private Thread thread;
        //public Main game;

    public int random(int min, int max) {
         int range = (max - min) + 1;     
        return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(achtergrond, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
        //g.drawImage(muisje, 10, 10, null);
        g.drawImage(muisje, random(0, this.getWidth()), random(0, this.getHeight()), null);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        Image achtergrond, muisje;
        JTextField invoer;
        JButton raden;
        JButton menu;

        Gamevenster() {
        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("assets/achtergrondspel.png"));
        achtergrond = icon.getImage();      

        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("assets/muisje.png"));
        muisje = icon2.getImage();   

        //Get the default toolkit  
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  

        //Load an image for the cursor  
        Image image = toolkit.getImage("src/assets/hand.png");  

        //Create the hotspot for the cursor  
        Point hotSpot = new Point(0,0);

        //Create the custom cursor  
        Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Hand");

        //Use the custom cursor  
        setCursor(cursor);

        // setLayout( null );

        // Invoer feld
        invoer = new JTextField(10);
        invoer.setLayout(null);
        invoer.setBounds(150, 474, 290, 60); // Verander positie onder aan scherm is int 1

        // Button voor raden
        raden = new JButton("Raden");
        raden.setLayout(null);
        raden.setBounds(10, 474, 130, 60);
        raden.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 20));
        raden.setForeground(Color.white);
        raden.setBackground(new Color(46, 204, 113));
        raden.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 60));

        // Menu knop
        menu = new JButton("Menu");
        menu.setLayout(null);
        menu.setBounds(450, 474, 130, 60);
        menu.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 20));
        menu.setForeground(Color.white);
        menu.setBackground(new Color(46, 204, 113));
        menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 60));

        // Toevoegen aan screen
        add(invoer);
        //add(raden);
        add(menu);

        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String i = invoer.getText();
        System.out.println("Er is gedrukt! " + i);
                }
            });
        }

        public void start(){
            thread = new Thread(this,"spelloop");
            thread.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(Gamestatus=="active"){
                System.out.println("Gameloop werkt");
            }
        }
}
```

as you can see I'm using g.drawImage(muisje, random(0, this.getWidth()), random(0, this.getHeight()), null);

So it randomly add the image on startup.

How can I use a timer to do this every x seconds when the app is openend?

Comment: [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Comment: Thanks, but since i'm fairly new to java I don't have a clue of how to use Timer in my app.

Comment: I'm a bit busy to explain it here, that's why I'm only giving links (sorry) but check out this [Timer Tutorial](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).

Comment: I can't get it to work. could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How can I use a timer to do this every x seconds when the app is openend?"

Have a look at this example. I gathered Images from the internet, but you can do the same using image files. What I did was use an array of `URL` and `BufferedImage` and got a random index ever 500 milliseconds and `repaint()` the panel

Note If you are going to use image files, you may want to look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21060858/2587435) also.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestImageRotate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Timer");
                frame.add(new ImagePanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        URL[] urls;
        BufferedImage[] images;
        Random rand = new Random();

        public ImagePanel() {
            urls = new URL[5];
            try {
                urls[0] = new URL("http://www.atomicframework.com/assetsY/img/stackoverflow_chicklet.png");
                urls[1] = new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/orange/stackoverflow-256.png");
                urls[2] = new URL("http://img.1mobile.com/market/screenshot/50/com.dd.stackoverflow/0.png");
                urls[3] = new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/orange/stackoverflow-4-512.png");
                urls[4] = new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/light-gray/stackoverflow-xxl.png");

                images = new BufferedImage[5];
                images[0] = ImageIO.read(urls[0]);
                images[1] = ImageIO.read(urls[1]);
                images[2] = ImageIO.read(urls[2]);
                images[3] = ImageIO.read(urls[3]);
                images[4] = ImageIO.read(urls[4]);

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        private int random() {
            int index = rand.nextInt(5);
            return index;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            BufferedImage img = images[random()];
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 400, 0, 0,
                    img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Notice the `Timer` code. This is all I did

```
Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }
});
timer.start();
```

And for the `.grawImage` I use a random index from the array of `BufferedImages`

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    BufferedImage img = images[random()];
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 400, 0, 0,
                           img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), this);
}
```

---

**UPDATE** Example. I shut down my IDE for the night. Too lazy to open so I'm just going to come up with this as I go. If you still don't it, I'll add a real example tomorrow when I get up.

Basically you want to have global variable for the x and y locations of the mouse image

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
```

When you draw the image, you want to use these locations

```
g.drawImage(img, x, y, whatEverWidth, whatEverHeight, this);
```

In the timer, you can modify the x and y randomly before you paint. Let use some logic.

Let say your scree width is 500 and screen height is 500 and mouse image width is 100 and mouse image height is 100

- So the max x location will be 400 = screen width - mouse image width
- And max y location will be 400 = screen height - mouse image height

So now we have our ranges. We know min x location is 0 and min y location is 0. So we want a random number from 0 to 400 for each x and y. So in the timer you can do

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x = rand.nextInt(400) + 1;     
        y = rand.nextInt(400) + 1;
        repaint();   
    }
});
```

This will repaint your mouse image at a random location every time repaint is called.

---

### UPDATE 2

I don't know what else is there to explain. I did *just* those things I pointed out(with my original code), just added an `x` and `y` and used them to draw the image, and got a random location in the `timer`. It's works perfectly fine for me. I don't know what you're doing wrong.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestImageRotate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Timer");
                frame.add(new ImagePanel());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        URL[] urls;
        BufferedImage[] images;
        Random rand = new Random();
        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 0;

        public ImagePanel() {
            urls = new URL[5];
            try {
                urls[0] = new URL("http://www.atomicframework.com/assetsY/img/stackoverflow_chicklet.png");
                urls[1] = new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/orange/stackoverflow-256.png");
                urls[2] = new URL("http://img.1mobile.com/market/screenshot/50/com.dd.stackoverflow/0.png");
                urls[3] = new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/orange/stackoverflow-4-512.png");
                urls[4] = new URL("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/light-gray/stackoverflow-xxl.png");

                images = new BufferedImage[5];
                images[0] = ImageIO.read(urls[0]);
                images[1] = ImageIO.read(urls[1]);
                images[2] = ImageIO.read(urls[2]);
                images[3] = ImageIO.read(urls[3]);
                images[4] = ImageIO.read(urls[4]);

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    x = rand.nextInt(325);
                    y = rand.nextInt(325);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        private int random() {
            int index = rand.nextInt(5);
            return index;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            BufferedImage img = images[random()];
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, 75, 75, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I combine this easily with the random g.drawimage image I provided in the OP?

Comment: so the mouse will repaint on different spots everytime it's repainting.

Comment: 1) I don't see why not. You just need to use an array of images, so you can get a random index for the array and repaint() every time the timer is called (which is every so many milliseconds). 2) I have no idea where this notion of a mouse is coming from. I thought your question had to do with a timer.

Comment: I see, the _image_ is a mouse. I thought you meant the computer mouse. No, the mouse will not repaint at random location. for that, you need to use varbiables for the `.drawImage` instead of hard coded locations like 0, 0, you would use x, y, where x, y can be updated in the timer also.

Comment: Could you give an example of that? It's not that easy for a beginner to understand the logic of Java.

Comment: I can't get it to work, the part for the timer gives me unknown errors.

Comment: If you have x, y, and Random rand declared globally, you should get no errors. Also make sure you imported javax.swing.Timer and not java.util.Timer

Comment: Ah okay! maybe that's the problem. Let's see.

Comment: Getting the error rand cannot be resolved. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you haven't declare `Random rand = new Random()` globally. You can save yourself the trouble and just declare it in the `actionPerformed` if you want. I was just trying to show you the correct way to do it.

Comment: It's not working, it doesn't move. http://pastebin.com/u1h7zs2F look at this code, I am doing it wrong, because nothing moves randomly. it just sits there.

Comment: It's a bad link. I _really_ hope you didn't declare x and y in the `paintComponent` method. There should only be one declaration globally. Both the `paintComponent` and the `timer` should be using the same `x` and `y`. Neither of the methods should be declaring a new one. Other than that, I don't know. And I'm going to sleep.

Comment: See my **UPDATE 2**. All I did was exactly the things I mentioned. Nothing more, nothing less. And it works fine for me.

Comment: Your second updatw worked, thanks a lot! It looks like I placed the timer.start in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am a beginner too. So if i misguide you i am sorry in advance. Thats my first answer.  What you are looking for is probably this
   `System.currentTimeMillis();`
this will give the current time as milisecs. So You will probably want to use another float to calculate passed time and lets name it deltaTime. You can find deltaTime by `deltaTime=System.currentTimeMillis();`  use this before while loop in run method. Then inside the loop, if `System.currentTimeMillis()-deltaTime` is bigger than x number(miliseconds), spawn a rat. And reset deltaTime.

And I see you didn't declared a x,y position integer to store rats x and y location. So declare 2 global variables for x and y of rats. if rats multiple that x and y int should be arrays with enough room to keep all your rats positions.

Make an method so every time a rat spawns, x and y of rat's location gets a random int. You actually figured it out in graphics section. But random function shouldn't be in there. Instead of random function x and y integers should be there. In your code it will randomize location of rat everytime it updates graphics. No that's not what you want (probably).

One more thing, your code actually won't work without update method called. You should put `update();` at the end of your while loop.

Sorry if i am mistaken or not clear enough. I am only a beginner interested in the same topics before.