# JFrame repaint(); error

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe, repaint

So, I'm currently working on making a ball that moves on keyboard command. My problem is that when I call `repaint();`, it gives me an error saying that it "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method repaint() from the type Component." What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class App extends JFrame{

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    public static int keyVal = 0, x = 10, y = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();   
        Ball();
        while(true){
        System.out.println(keyVal);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        }
    }

    public static void Ball(){
        while(true){
            if(keyVal == 65){
            x = x -1;
            }
            else if(keyVal == 68){
            x = x + 1;
            }
        repaint();
        //repaint(x, y, 10, 20);
        }
    }

    public App(){
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("Pong");
        f.setSize(30,40);

        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                keyVal = e.getKeyCode();
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
                keyVal = 0;
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
        });
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500,200);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);       
            System.out.println("test");
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 20);
        }  
    }    
}
```

Comment: You need to call repaint() on an instance. i.e. ```f.repaint()```

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and complete working examples.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your class is already a `JFrame` subclass. There's no need to create another `JFrame`. Take out the `JFrame f = new JFrame()` and all the `f.method(..)` just use `method(..)`
2. Don't use `while(true)` or `Thread.sleep()`. You will run into problem. Instead look into [**How to use a Swing Timer**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). Here is a simple [**example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315495/2587435). You could also find many other examples just doing a simple google search on how to use Swing Timer
3. No need to `setSize()` to the frame, you already `pack()` it.
4. You should look into [**How to use Key Bindings**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). If not now, you will come to find that there are focus issues, among other things, with using a `KeyListener`.
5. Run your program from the [**Event Dispatch Thead**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), like this

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               new App();
           }
       });
   }
   ```

---

Freebie

A simple implementation of a `javax.swing.Timer` would be something like this

```
public App() {
    ...
    Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // do something
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the basic construct of the `Timer`

```
Timer( int dalay, ActionListener listener )
```

The delay it the amount of milliseconds delayed for each time the event is fired. So in the above code, for every 50 milliseconds, something will happen. This will achieve what you are trying to do with the `Thread.sleep`. You can call the `repaint()` from inside the `actionPerformed`

---

Here's a simple refactor of your code, that you can test out

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class App extends JFrame {

    private MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    public static int keyVal = 0, x = 10, y = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new App();
            }
        });
    }

    public App() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    x = x + 5;

                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Pong");
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        public MyPanel() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 200);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("test");
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try that and get back to you A.S.A.P.

Comment: +1 excelent answer, one two years and will be like as by MadProgramer or HFOE