# JPanel causing extra space to the side?

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, jpanel, delay

I made a simple program that uses `drawString()` to draw on a JPanel that gets repainted to change the background to a random color.  It works fine, other than the ~10 pixel spaces to the right side and bottom side of the JPanel, which remain the default color.  I think this problem might be happening because of the way I use `pack()` or `getPrefferedSize()`.  Any help or suggestions to fix this are appreciated.

Birthday.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Birthday {

    DrawString panel = new DrawString();

    public Birthday() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel);
        f.setTitle("Happy Birthday!");
        f.setLocation(10, 10);
        f.pack();

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Birthday();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

DrawString.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawString extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int x = 350;
        int y = 250;
        int red   = random(0,255);
        int green = random(0,255);
        int blue  = random(0,255);
        Color black = new Color(0,0,0);

        Color newColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
        g.setColor(newColor);
        g.fillRect(0,0,1000,500);
        g.setColor(black);
        g.setFont(new Font(null,Font.BOLD,40));
        g.drawString("Happy Birthday!",x,y);
    }

    public static int random(int min, int max)
    {
        int range = max - min + 1;
        int number = (int) (range * Math.random() + min);
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Birthday.class gets two errors at compilation error: no suitable method found for paintComponent() and error: non-static method delay(int) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: So could you please paste those into the question? It would be quite helpful.

Comment: Yes, I'll add that right now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You **never** want to explicitly call `paintComponent`. Instead if you want the panel to repaint, you can call `panel.repaint()`, and the panel with implicitly call its own `paintComponent` method for you.
2. Don't do every thing inside the `main` method, you'll find you're going to run into a lot of problems with `static` references.
3. Don't use `Thread.sleep()`, it will block the [**Event Dispatch Thread**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)., as that's where you should be running you Swing apps from. Instead use a `java.swing.Timer`. See [**this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315495/2587435) for `Timer` usage.
4. As noted in 3, run your Swing apps from the EDT like this

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
           public void run() {
               new MyApp();
           }
       });
   }
   ```
5. Don't set the size of your frame. Instead override `getPreferredSize()` of your `DrawingPanel` and just `pack()` the frame.
6. You can center the frame by using `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`
7. Should make it a habit to use the @Override annotation to make sure you are override correctly.

---

Add-on to 2. What you make a habit of doing, is doing your work from the constructor, then just calling the constructor in the `main`.  Here is a refactor of your code with all the above mentioned things fixed. You can run it.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Birthday {

    DrawString panel = new DrawString();

    public Birthday() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(panel);
        f.setTitle("Happy Birthday!");
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Birthday();
            }
        });
    }
}

class DrawString extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int x = 350;
        int y = 250;
        int red = random(0, 255);
        int green = random(0, 255);
        int blue = random(0, 255);
        Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);

        Color newColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        g.setColor(newColor);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(black);
        g.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 40));
        g.drawString("Happy Birthday!", x, y);
    }

    public static int random(int min, int max) {
        int range = max - min + 1;
        int number = (int) (range * Math.random() + min);
        return number;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1000, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your help solved all of my errors and I learned a couple new things while fixing it. Also, do you know of any other good examples or sites that I can learn more with java? I'm mostly learning on my own with some examples from others.

Comment: Best place is the Java Swing tutorials [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). For basic Java [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). Also please accept this answer if it works for you. (the check mark)

Comment: Thanks again for the help, this solved a problem for this program, but also will help me to solve one of the problems in another, larger program I have been working on.