# Doing some actions after hitting button

Tags: java, awt

I have written code in java:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class ProstyApplet extends Applet
{
    Button b1 = new Button("BUTTON");
    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("START");
        b1.addActionListener(new B1());
        add(b1);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(150,150,100,100);
    }
    class B1 implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //here I want to draw rectangle
        }
    }

}
```

I have created button `B1` and I created `ActionListener` for `B1`. I want my program to draw rectangle when I click it but I have problem with using `paint()`, `repaint()` methods to do so. What is the way to draw rectangle after pressing the button?

Comment: Could you explain what kind of problem you have?

Comment: @joragupra I simply do not know the way how to draw rectangle after hitting the button. I searched the web but could not find any examples that may help me.

Comment: First of all, use Swing, not AWT. Then next, read the tutorials on use of 1) [JButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), 2) [ActionListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and on 3) [painting with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Then give it a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it goes. The `paint()` methods should paint a list of things to paint. The `actionPerformed()` method should simply add, remove or modify the things to paint, and then ask the applet to repaint. The `paint()` methods will then be called by AWT again, will iterate through the things to paint, and paint them.

Comment: Thank you. I get it. But would you mind explaining how to modify paint() method ?

Comment: The paint() should get the Rectangle(s) from the list of things to draw, and draw the rectangle(s). Read the javadoc of Graphics.

Comment: @MarcinMajewski see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22123304/2587435). You can add objects to a `List` in the `actionPerformed`, then `repaint()`. You _don't_ _"modify"_ the `paint`, you loop through the `List` in the `paint` method, as seen in example.