# Simple animations in Java

Tags: java, swing, animation, netbeans, graphics

I'm attempting to code a simple animation or physics example in a Java Swing application. I have the actual windows application open and working, but I can't figure out how to actually draw my shapes, and how I'd format the code for calculations between frames, that sort of stuff.

I've read some stuff about over riding a paint method, but I don't know what that means, and I don't believe I'm using it in the code I'm using right now. This is my code:

```
public class Physics extends JFrame{

public Physics() {

    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    panel.setLayout(null);

    final JLabel label = new JLabel("Hi, press the button to do something");
    label.setBounds(20, 0, 2000, 60);


    final JButton submitButton = new JButton("Start");
    submitButton.setBounds(20, 150, 80, 20);
    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Put button code here later
        }
    });

    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(submitButton);

    setTitle("Program");
    setSize(300, 250);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Physics ex = new Physics();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

}
```

So I have some blank space above my button where I'd like to draw maybe a square or circle moving across the screen to start off with, once I get that down I can start getting into the more advanced stuff. Any hints on how to do that would be appriciated :D

Thanks!

Comment: I've used this good tutorial http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/ when I was learning Java 2D. Honestly, this question should be revised, because it's not really a question more like asking for a suggestion

Comment: I think it's still a question, I'm asking how to add an animation or a shape into my application. I'll take a look at your link

Answer (score 6):

> "I've read some stuff about over riding a paint method, but I don't know what that means"

So you've overridden `actionPerformed`, so you know what an `@Override` is. As you'll notice from the `ActionListener`, you never *actually* explicitly call `actionPerformed`, but whatever you put in the there, still get's used. That's because the `ActionListener` implicitly call it for you.

The same is true with painting. In the Swing painting process, there is a paint chain that Swing uses to paint components.  Along the way `paint` is called somewhere. So just like `actionPerformed`, you can override `paint` and it will get implicitly called for you.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
}
```

The `Graphics` object passed to the method is the graphics context that Swing will use for the painting. You can look at the [`Graphics API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) to see the methods you can use. You can use [`drawOval`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to draw a circle

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Now here's the thing. You don't actually want to override `paint`. In the tutorials linked above, some of the examples will use applets and override `paint`, but you shouldn'y paint on top level containers like `JFrame` or `JApplet`. Instead paint on a `JPanel` or `JComponent` and just add it the `JFrame`. When you *do* paint on `JPanel` or `JComponent`, you'll instead override `paintComponent` (which also gets called along the paint chain), instead of `paint`

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
}
```

You see how I used variables for the `drawOval` method. The `x` is the x location from the top-let of the screen, and `y` and the y point. `width` and `height` are width and height of the circle. The great thing about using variables is that their values can be changed at runtime.

That's where the animation comes to play. As pointed out, you an use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

The basic construct is

```
public Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener) {
}
```

The `delay` is the milliseconds to delay each call to the listener. The listener will have your `actionPerformed` call back that will do what's inside, every `delay` milliseconds. So what you can do, is just change the `x` from the `drawOval` and `repaint()`, and it will animate. Something like

```
Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x += 5;
        repaint();
    }
});
timer.start();
```

The timer code you can just put in the constructor. That's probably simplest explanation I can give. Hope it helps.

Don't forget the to see [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Grapics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more advance topics on graphics. Also see some example of timers and animation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871022/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593458/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534549/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801845/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315495/2587435)

---

Also avoid using null layouts. See [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to learn how to use layout managers, as should be done with Swing apps.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html).

The example shows you how to do painting. If you want animation, then you would use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the animation. The tutorial also has a section on `How to use a Swing Timer`.

Put the two tutorial together and you have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are any number of ways to achieve this.

Start by taking a look at:

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

For details about how painting in Swing is done.

Animation is not as simple as just pausing a small period of time and then repainting, theres acceleration and deceleration and other concepts that need to be considered.

While you could write your own, that's not a small task, a better solution might be to use a pre-existing engine, for example...

Then take a look at:

- [Timing Framework](https://java.net/projects/TimingFramework)
- [Trident](https://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)
- [java-universal-tween-engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)

Which are all examples of animation engines in Swing.  While I prefer the Timing Framework as it provides me with a lower level API, this is a personal opinion.  Both Trident and the JUWE seem to be geared more towards component/property based animation (which the Timing Framework can do if you want to build some of the feature sets up)

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple animation with two rockets blasting off. The full eclipse project is here: https://github.com/CoachEd/JavaExamples/tree/master/RaceToSpace. Here's a screenshot:
[image]