# Animation using a timer?

Tags: java, timer

I'm trying to understand how to use one some kind of basic animation. I can use threads, but I was told by  multiple people not to multi-thread in java. I think I cold do something like:

```
Timer t = new Timer(10, somthing);
t.start();
x++;
t.end();
```

That's my basic understanding of it. Can someone link a tutorial or explain how to make a time do something every 10 seconds or longer?

Answer (score 0):

First, why were you told not to multithread? That seems like a pretty limiting rule for modern computers.

It seems as if you wanna schedule a task to fire at a given rate. You should look into `Timer#schedule()`. It allows you to pass in a task, as well as some configuration for timing that task.

```
public class TimerDemo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          // creating timer task, timer
          TimerTask tasknew = new TimerSchedulePeriod();
          Timer timer = new Timer();

          // scheduling the task at interval
          timer.schedule(tasknew, 0, 10);      
     }

    // this method performs the task
    public void run() {
         System.out.println("timer working");      
    }    
}
```

Source of code: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a swing timer, you can make one like this:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
//delayed timer
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      //do your code after a delay (delayInMillis)
    }
    }, delayInMillis);

//repeating timer

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      //do your code every repeatTimeInMillis
    }
    }, 0, repeatTimeInMillis;
```

My suggestion for animations is to create an integer in which you change with the timers.  When you are drawing your animation, you can draw a specific image if the int is a specific variable. (Using if-else statemtents or a switch statement)

I hope I helped :D

Answer (score 0):

"Not to multithread in Java" doesn't sound right. The advice was maybe geared towards Swing and to run your app/do your painting on the Event Dispatch Thread. In which case you would want to do the animation with a `java.swing.Timer`. The basic construct is

```
Timer( int deleyInMillis, ActionListener listener )
```

where the `delayInMillis` is the milliseconds delayed between `ActionEvents` fired by the timer. The `ActionListener` will be the listener listing for the `ActionEvents`. So every `delayInMillis` the `actionPerformed` method will be called.

So you could do something like

```
Timer timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (someStoppingCondition) {
            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();  
        } else {
            // do something every ten seconds.
        }
    }
});
timer.start();
```

You can see more at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). You can also see a bunch of examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21871022/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593458/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534549/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801845/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315495/2587435) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22123304/2587435).